# How to use bootstrap and tailwind CSS for a same div?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, node-modules, bootstrap-5

```
<h1 class="tw-text-white tw-text-2xl tw-font-sans tw-bg-slate-800">
Hello 

</h1>
you
  clicked {{counter}}
```

In the button tag .btn is from bootstrap and the tw-bg-slate-900 is from tailwind

I want to use both bootstrap and tailwind or primarily tailwind, Bootstrap is for I need to design faster like (accessing the bootstrap component) Kindly help me on this. As for now bootstrap is overlapping the tailwind CSS.

**This is in angular, so I installed them both locally using npm install**

for example:

```
<button class="btn tw-bg-slate-900 " (click)="onClick()">you   clicked {{counter}} </button>
```

in this button tag I wanted to use the bootstrap ('btn') class, but background is tailwind ('tw-bg-slate-900'). So, both of them are needed.

Below snippets are index.html and index.css of the angular

```
 /*styles.css */
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components; 
@tailwind utilities;


/*tailwind.config */
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
module.exports = { 
  content: [     "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",   ],
   prefix: "tw-",
   theme: {     extend: {},
   },
   plugins: [],
 }
```

angular.json

```
         ....
       "styles": [ 
                  "src/styles.css", 
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"             
        ],
         ....
```

I override the bootstrap class `btn` like this.

```
.btn {  
     @apply tw-bg-slate-900 
}
```

Expectation:

I can use both the frameworks for a same div.
Tailwinds is more primary, bootstrap is for styling some components quickly, because of the prebuild components.
I need to override the Bootstrap with Tailwind CSS

Comment: This is a bad idea. Using both may be fine if you're using tailwind for layouts only as an alternative to css. The moment you start trying to override the design system of a component you're in for a bad time

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Yogi I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comments @AndrewAllen, yes, I'm using the tailwind for the layout and bootstrap for the normal styling the components.

Comment: Thank you for editing my clumsy question @JamesZ